# Recursive function doesn't seem to work

Tags: recursion

So I'm writing this app where a user can put objects (cards) on a wall. if the position on the wall is already taken by a card, this card needs to be moved. however, if the next position is already taken as well, we'll have to move that card as well and so on.

So I thought that a recursive function would be the best for this problem, right? 
My (pseudo) code is like this:

```
private void moveCard(int row, int column){   //row, column = position on the wall
    if(column >= length of wall)
        return;

    if(position at row, column is empty)
        move card to the right;
    else
        moveCard(row, column+1);
```

However, only the last card in a row gets moved! I'm not the best in writing recursive functions to be honest. Any idea what my problem is?

Comment: After you move the card that's in the way, you have to move the current card.

Comment: We need a [mcve], not pseudocode.

Comment: What happens if you can't move the card that's in the way, because all the spaces from there to the end of the wall are filled?

Comment: You're approaching this very strangely, either use recursion to get the new index, or do the whole thing in a normal loop instead. But you're trying to do both in recursion!

Comment: @user2357112 - Pseudo code works just fine, so long as it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

After you move the card on the right out of the way, you have to move the current card.

```
private void moveCard(int row, int column){   //row, column = position on the wall
    if(column >= length of wall)
        return;

    if(position at row, column is empty)
        move card to the right;
    else {
        moveCard(row, column+1);
        if (position at row, column is empty)
            move card to the right;
    }
```

Notice that you have to check again whether the position is empty, in case the recursive call couldn't move the card because all the spaces to the right are full.

You could also have the function return a boolean that indicates whether it was successful at moving the card, and you could check that instead of testing whether the space is empty.